# lintr no visible binding for global variable ‘.SD’

Tags: r, data.table, linter, lintr

`lintr` throws error while using `data.table` functions like `.SD`, `.SDcols`, e.g:

```
/path/readData.R:130:29: warning: no visible binding for global variable ‘.SD’, Did you mean 'SSD'?
      DT[, "row.sum" := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols =  names(DT)]
                                ^~~
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `help("globalVariables")`? At least that works when checking packages with R CMD check.

Answer (score 3):

Add `linters: with_defaults(object_usage_linter = NULL)` to your .lintr file.

Comment: Well, yes this removes the warning, but it also is massive overkill, as now lintr will not check for any variables.